# pass boolean state value from parent class to child class when a button is clicked in the parent class in react js so that i can load quizes with bool

Tags: reactjs

parent class Welcome

here im clicking a button called Rookie which triggers the state value for that level and i want to send that val to Quiz class so that i can use it for displaying Quizes. I dont know if this is correct what im doing right now

```
class Welcome extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewquiz: false,
      people: [],
      dataHasLoaded: false,
      user: {},
      viewProfile: false

      // viewLogin:false
    };
    this.changeToquiz1 = this.changeToquiz1.bind(this);
  }
  changeToquiz1 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: true,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    });
  };

  changeToquiz2 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: true,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    });
    console.log("quiz2 clciked");
  };

  changeToquiz3 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: true,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    });
  };
  changeToquiz4 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: true,
      level5: false
    });
  };
  changeToquiz5 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: true
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
    this.retrieveData();
    console.log("Data loaded");
  }

  authListener = () => {
    //checks if user is already logged in 0n browser
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          user
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
      }
      return user;
    });
  };
  retrieveData = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        var ref = fire
          .database()
          .ref("data")
          .limitToLast(1);
        //takes the last data in DB

        var userUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var query = ref.orderByChild("ID").equalTo(userUID); //retrieves data about only the current logged in user
        console.log(userUID);
        query.once("value", snapshot => {
          let currentState = this.state.people;

          const currentUser = snapshot.val();
          for (let i in currentUser) {
            currentState.push({
              email: currentUser[i].UserEmail,
              UserAnswer: currentUser[i].UserAnswer,
              Questions: currentUser[i].Question,
              id: currentUser[i].ID,
              Score: currentUser[i].Score,
              Level: currentUser[i].userLevel
            });
          }
          // currentState.push(user);
          console.log(currentState);

          this.setState({
            people: currentState,
            dataHasLoaded: true
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log("no user");
      }
    });
  };

  changetoQuiz = () => {
    this.setState({
      viewquiz: true
    });
  };
  changetoProfile = () => {
    this.setState({
      viewProfile: !this.state.viewProfile
    });
  };

  logout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signOut();
    console.log("Logged out");
  };

  render() {
    const x = this.props.stateQuiz1;

    let renderData = this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
      return (
        <div style={{ color: " black" }} key={index}>
          {this.state.viewProfile ? (
            <UserProfile
              className="userProfile"
              level={person.UserLevel}
              score={person.Score}
              question={person.Questions}
              email={person.email}
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      );
    });

    let loadingSpinner = <Loader id="loader" type="ThreeDots" color="red " />;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Navbar id="navbar" bg="primary" variant="dark">
            <Nav className="mr-auto" style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>
              Welcome
              <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button onClick={this.changeToquiz1}>Rookie</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.changeToquiz2}>Student</Button>
                <Button>Intermediate</Button>
                <Button>Expert</Button>
                <Button>Master</Button>
              </ButtonToolbar>
            </Nav>
            <Button onClick={this.logout}>
              <Nav>
                Logout <FiLogOut />
              </Nav>
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.changetoProfile}>
              <Nav>
                Profile <MdPerson />
              </Nav>
            </Button>
          </Navbar>

          <Test stateOutput={this.changeToquiz1} />
        </div>

        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
          <h3 className="heading" style={{ color: "black" }}>
            Guarding <GiSwordsEmblem />
          </h3>
          <p className="groove">
            Fixed guards must always be kept in place. These prevent
            entanglement The guard should ensure that no part of your body can
            reach the danger zone Fixed guarding of older machines should be
            upgraded in line with the guarding on newer models Do not use a
            machine unless all guards are in place
          </p>

          <h3 className="heading" style={{ color: "black" }}>
            Machinery Checks <MdCheckBox />
            <p className="groove">
              All safety guards/ devices fitted The PTO "O" guards present
              Hydraulic systems and hoses in good repair All machinery defects
              identified and corrected Regular maintenance carried out
            </p>
          </h3>

          <h3 className="heading" style={{ color: "black" }}>
            Machinery Checks <MdCheckBox />
            <p className="groove">
              All safety guards/ devices fitted The PTO "O" guards present
              Hydraulic systems and hoses in good repair All machinery defects
              identified and corrected Regular maintenance carried out
            </p>
          </h3>
          <h3 className="heading" style={{ color: "black" }}>
            Machinery Fatalities <MdCheckBox />
            <p className="groove">
              Tractors and Machinery are the main cause of farm accidents in
              Ireland. Elderly farmers and children are at particular risk.
              Being entangled in PTO’s, crushed under a machine part, caught in
              a machine mechanism, crushed between vehicles and struck by a
              machine object are the main causes of deaths with farm machinery.
              <img src={piechart} alt="" />
            </p>
          </h3>
          {<div>{this.state.dataHasLoaded ? renderData : loadingSpinner}</div>}
          <Button onClick={this.changetoQuiz}>Take the Quiz</Button>

          {this.state.viewquiz ? (
            <Quiz stateOutput={this.changeToquiz1} />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Welcome;
```

child class Quiz
here i want to use the boolean state value that has been recieved from Welcome class
I am checking the level1,2,3,4.. boolean vals so that i can load the quizes accordingly in the componentDidMount

```
class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userAns: null,
      options: [],
      disabled: false,
      currentQuest: 0,
      isEnd: false,
      scores: 0,
      pictures: "",
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    };
    //  this.changeToquiz2 = this.changeToquiz2.bind();
  }
  loadQuiz = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    //  console.log(Quizdata[2].question);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        questions: Quizdata[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.answer);
  };
  loadQuiz2 = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    //  console.log(Quizdata[2].question);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        questions: Quizdata2[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata2[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata2[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata2[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.answer);
  };
  loadQuiz3 = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    //  console.log(Quizdata[2].question);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        questions: Quizdata3[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata3[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata3[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata3[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.answer);
  };
  false;
  loadQuiz4 = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    //  console.log(Quizdata[2].question);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        questions: Quizdata4[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata4[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata4[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata4[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.answer);
  };
  loadQuiz5 = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    //  console.log(Quizdata[2].question);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        questions: Quizdata5[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata5[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata5[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata5[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.answer);
  };

  changeToquiz1 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: true,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    });
  };

  changeToquiz2 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: true,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    });
  };
  changeToquiz3 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: true,
      level4: false,
      level5: false
    });
  };
  changeToquiz4 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: true,
      level5: false
    });
  };
  changeToquiz5 = () => {
    this.setState({
      level1: false,
      level2: false,
      level3: false,
      level4: false,
      level5: true
    });
  };

  nextQuestion = e => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.userAns === null) {
      alert("choose an option");
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      currentQuest: this.state.currentQuest + 1
    });
    this.setState({
      userAns: null
    });
    // console.log(this.state.currentQuest);
  };

  checkAns = userAns => {
    const { answer, scores } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      userAns: answer,
      disabled: false
    });
    console.log(userAns);
    if (userAns === answer) {
      console.log("Correct");
      this.setState({
        scores: scores + 1
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Wrong");
      alert("Correct answer is " + answer);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.level1) {
      this.loadQuiz();
      console.log("Quiz1 loaded"); //loads quiz  data in
    }
    if (this.state.level2) {
      this.loadQuiz2(); //loads quiz  data in
      console.log("Quiz2 loaded");
    }
    if (this.state.level3) {
      this.loadQuiz3(); //loads quiz  data i
      console.log("Quiz3 loaded");
    }
    if (this.state.level4) {
      this.loadQuiz4(); //changeToquiz2 quiz  data in
      console.log("Quiz4 loaded");
    }
    if (this.state.level5) {
      this.loadQuiz5(); //loads quiz  data in
      console.log("Quiz5 loaded");
    } else {
      console.log("No user states changed");
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    if (this.state.currentQuest !== prevState.currentQuest) {
      this.setState({
        disabled: true,
        questions: Quizdata[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata[currentQuest].picture
      });
    }
  }

  logout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signOut();
    console.log("Logged out");
  };

  pushtoDB = () => {
    var ref = fire.database().ref("data");
    var newRef = ref.push();
    newRef.set({
      ID: fire.auth().currentUser.uid,
      UserEmail: fire.auth().currentUser.email,
      Question: this.state.questions, //Send data to DB to track for analysis
      UserAnswer: this.state.userAns,
      Score: this.state.scores,
      userLevel: this.state.level1
    });

    console.log("Sent to Database");
  };

  pushtoDB2 = () => {
    var ref = fire.database().ref("data");
    var newRef = ref.push();
    newRef.set({
      ID: fire.auth().currentUser.uid,
      UserEmail: fire.auth().currentUser.email,
      Question: this.state.questions, //Send data to DB to track for analysis
      UserAnswer: this.state.userAns,
      Score: this.state.scores,
      userLevel: this.state.level1
    });
    console.log("Sent to Database");
  };

  finishQuiz = () => {
    if (this.state.currentQuestion === Quizdata.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        isEnd: true
      });
      return (
        <h3>
          Quiz Finished, You scored {this.state.scores}/{Quizdata.length - 1}!
        </h3>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { userAns, options, currentQuest, isEnd } = this.state;
    if (isEnd) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Alert>Quiz Finished</Alert>
          <span>
            Quiz score : {this.state.scores}/{Quizdata.length - 1}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="quizForm">
          <br></br>
          {/*  <Welcome stateQuiz1={this.changeToquiz2} />*/}

          <div>
            <ProgressBar animated now={this.state.currentQuest * 10} />
          </div>
          {this.state.questions}
          <br></br>
          <p>Q{this.state.currentQuest}</p>

          {this.state.pictures}
          <br></br>
          {options.map(option => (
            <Button
              size="lg"
              block
              key={option.id}
              className={`ui floating message options
            ${userAns === option ? "selected" : null}
           `}
              onClick={() => this.checkAns(option)}
            >
              {option}
            </Button>
          ))}

          <br></br>
          <Button onClick={() => this.checkAns()}>
            CHECK <FaHorse />
          </Button>
          {currentQuest < Quizdata.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
              onClick={() => {
                this.nextQuestion();
                this.pushtoDB();
              }}
            >
              NEXT <FaArrowRight />
            </Button>
          )}
          <br></br>

          {currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                this.pushtoDB2();
                this.finishQuiz();
                this.chooseLevel1();
              }}
            >
              Finish
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default Quiz;
```

Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the state values then while calling your `Quiz` child component just pass that values as props. In your code, while calling `Quiz` component you are passing `changeToquiz1` method as a prop.

Instead pass all the required values using parent component's state. e.g.

```
<Quiz level1={this.state.level1} />
```

In `Quiz` component's props you will get updated values so just use ts as `this.props.level1`.

Comment: but where do i use the props in the Quiz? like where